# UITableViewCell reorder control clips view in iOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, uitableview

I put a background image in a UITableViewCell to make it more visually appealing. In iOS 13, the background image is clipped by the reorder control.

[image]

This did not happen with older versions of the OS.

[image]

The code is simple:

```
    // Put a border around mBackgroundImage. Make it slightly smaller than the size of the cell so that the border doesn't run all the way to the edges.
cell.mBackgroundImage.frame = CGRectMake(2, 2, cell.frame.size.width-4, cell.frame.size.height-4);
cell.mBackgroundImage.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
cell.mBackgroundImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.92 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
cell.mBackgroundImage.layer.borderWidth = 1;
cell.mBackgroundImage.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:0.95 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you adding the `mBackgroundImage` to the `cell` or to the `cell`'s `contentView`?

Comment: mBackgroundImage is in the cell's contentView.

Comment: Aha! I’m sizing mBackgroundImage based on the cell's frame, not the contentView's frame. And it appears that the default setting for cell.contentView.clipsToBounds has changed in iOS 13. If I explicitly set it to NO, I get the desired behavior. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Thinking about this some more I think what probably happened is that iOS 13 fixed a bug in previous versions of iOS: cell.contentView.clipsToBounds=YES had been ignored.

Comment: You should manipulate layer in `layoutSubviews`. Where is your code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by setting cell.contentView.clipsToBounds to NO. It looks like cell.contentView.clipsToBounds=YES had been ignored prior to iOS 13.